# Prove gauge invariance (reminder)

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance

In the book [Condensed matter field theory](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521769752), there is the exercise on p17 to check that the $Aj$-coupling is gauge invariant $A_\mu\rightarrow A_\mu\partial_\mu \Gamma$, where $\Gamma$ is an arbitrary function. I'm a little rusty on this. I have

$$
\int A_\mu j^\mu d^4x \rightarrow \int (A_\mu + \partial_\mu\Gamma)j^\mu d^4x,
$$

and the second term must be zero (in order to be gauge invariant). Integrating by parts the second term I get

$$
\int \partial_\mu(\Gamma) j^\mu d^4x = \Gamma j^\mu|_? + \int \Gamma \partial_\mu j^\mu d^4x.
$$

the second term is zero by current conservation, but what is the argument to get rid of the first term? Also, where do you evaluate it?

Comment: $\Gamma$ (and often $j$) is required to vanish on the boundary.

Comment: Yeah, right, but is this a physical statement, or a mathematical convenience?

Comment: Physical. It comes requirement of finite energy.

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: its both. its finiteness of energy-momentum flux, angular momentum flux and charge flux through the boundary of the system (which is at infinity here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is customary in theoretical physics to just throw away boundary terms without worry. The exact reason why you can do this depends on what you're doing, and can often be quite mathematically technical.

In this case for instance the integration is taken on the whole space. Since you're doing a $4D$ integral, the boundary term is actually another integral. You can think of it as integrating on the "sphere at infinity". In concrete terms, it would be sufficient to require that $j^\mu\to 0$ at infinity while $\Gamma$ is bounded. Why do we require this? It's reasonable to expect that it holds if the source is localised, for instance. Other arguments might compute the total charge $Q=\int j^0$. For instance if $j^\mu \to c\neq 0$ constant, then $Q$ would be infinite, which depending on the situation may be unphysical. However there's a lot of technical issues here (for example, there are unbounded functions with finite integral). In other settings (variational principles), you may assume that the variation is compactly supported on the integration interval to annihilate boundary terms, but then other issues arise.

The upshot is: throw away those boundary terms! They will almost always be irrelevant. There are cases when they aren't, but the author will surely point that out.